# How to render html http response to a new page or a new component in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, rendering, httpresponse

I am wondering if there is a way to render http response that is html in a new page or in a new component? The specific problem is described below.

code to call the backend:

```
const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}  
let obs = this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/project/Raffle", _data,{ headers, responseType: 'text' as 'json'});
obs.subscribe((response)=>console.log(response));
```

The response is an html page displayed in the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Thank you for taking the survey! You win the raffle of two movie tickets!</title>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

My question is how may I render the content in a new component or possibly as a new html page?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a template using the output and Handlebar.js and display it as an html page.

Please refer to this resources=>

https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars

https://handlebarsjs.com/